# The constant term after 1st differencing

Tags: time-series, econometrics, trend, stationarity

My instructor stated that when the dependent variable is 1st differenced, the constant term represents the deterministic change or trend in the dependent variable.

When I search for information about deterministic trends, I am getting conflicting/confusing results.  The site below describes the differences between trend-stationarity and difference-stationarity.

What I am taking from this website is that differencing the data does not result in a constant term that can be represented as a deterministic trend.  And if the series contains a deterministic trend, differencing is usually not performed.

Can someone help clarify this for me?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/trend-stationary-vs-difference-stationary.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say you have a model
$$ 
y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t + \epsilon_t
$$
where $y_t$ and $x_t$ are your variables and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are your intercept (constant) and slope, respectively, then obviously
$$ 
y_{t-1} = \alpha + \beta x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1}
$$
From first-differencing you get
$$ 
y_t - y_{t-1} = (\alpha + \beta x_t + \epsilon_t) - ( \alpha + \beta x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1} )
$$
which simplifies to
$$ 
\Delta y_t = \beta \Delta x_t + \eta_t
$$
where $\Delta$ is the difference operator and $\eta_t$ is the new error term. Obviously the constant $\alpha$ disappeared, because it is time-invariant and cancels out during the differencing.
But now assume your model was
$$ 
y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t + \delta t + \epsilon_t
$$
which means it included a trend term $\delta t$. Then first-differencing will give you
$$ 
y_t - y_{t-1} = (\alpha + \beta x_t + \delta t + \epsilon_t) - ( \alpha + \beta x_{t-1} + \delta [t-1] + \epsilon_{t-1} )
$$
which again simplifies to
$$ 
\Delta y_t = \delta + \beta \Delta x_t + \eta_t
$$
Notice that the only difference between the first "1st-dif" model and this one is $\delta$, which now "looks" like a constant. But remember from the original model that it was the trend term. So your instructor is right.

Think about it like this: how much does $y_t$ change from one period to the next one (which is what $\Delta y_t$ means)? It changes by $\beta$ times the change in $x_t$ *plus* $\delta$, viz your trend.

Comment: Thank you very much.  So if there is no trend, there will be no constant term.  If there is a trend, regardless if it is stochastic or deterministic, it will be represented by the constant.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Amaziah yes, as long as you are careful about what you mean by "constant term" (in this case it should mean $\delta$)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and clear explanations.