# How fixed effect's mechanism works

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, dataset, fixed-effects-model

It is stated in my econometrics book that fixed effects and first differences estimators when t=2 produce the same result. Trying to demonstrate this statement has led me to see that I haven't understood fixed effects. I tried to do a simulation on R to see if the results for the two methods were the same but as you can see it didn't work. I will describe the way in which I proceeded so that you can tell me what is the error(s), I suspect that I'm doing an error with the fixed effect procedure.

Here we have two variables at two different times and three units. So I have calculated the mean over time for each individual and variables, then since my textbook says that I have to use pooled OLS estimator (maybe this is the crucial point) I have calculated the difference (for each observation and each variable in the two time period), between the value of the observation and the time mean (for example consider the variable x, the mean over time for the first individual is equal to (2+2)/2, hence the time-demeaned value is equal to 0 in t=1 and O in t=2) then I have created two vectors (x-demeaned and y-demeaned) and I have used the ordinary least squares procedure as I do with cross-sectional data (So I have doubled the observation in this way). Then I have also used first differences to compare the result, here the procedure is simpler. I just created two vectors (a,b) composed by the variation over time of the two variables. The result are different, I hope you can tell me how i should have used fixed effect.

```
  x1=c(2,4,6)   
  x2=c(2,7,5)
  y1=c(1,6,9)
  y2=c(3,5,8)
  xdemeaned=c(0,-1.5,0.5,0,1.5,-0.5)
  ydemeaned=c(-1,0.5,0.5,1,-0.5,-0.5)
  a=y2-y1
  b=x2-x1
  lm(a~b)         
  lm(ydemeaned~xdemeaned)

  Call:
  lm(formula = a ~ b)

  Coefficients:
  (Intercept)            b  
  0.1538      -0.2308  

    Call:
    lm(formula = ydemeaned ~ xdemeaned)

   Coefficients:
   (Intercept)    xdemeaned  
   2.266e-18   -2.000e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly note that fixed effects (FE) and first-differences (FD) *should* be similar when $T = 2$. The slight difference you are observing is due to the estimation of the *intercept* in an FD equation. The intercept usually drops out after differencing. In some contexts, you might want to estimate a *time trend*, even in a two period case; the intercept *is* that deterministic change. I encourage you to read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142835/the-constant-term-after-1st-differencing) which details the derivation.

I will reproduce your results using the `lm()` function on the *transformed data*. Be mindful, the standard errors will likely be off, in part because they require *different transformations* of the simulated data. I will follow-up with a second test using the `plm()` function. To begin, I created a stacked data frame which can easily be reproduced by others.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

data_raw <- tibble(
   id = as.character(c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 2))),
   time = as.character(rep(c(1, 2), 3)),
   y = c(1, 3, 6, 5, 9, 8),
   x = c(2, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5)
   )

data_trans <- data_raw %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(
      y_demeaned = y - mean(y),
      x_demeaned = x - mean(x),
      y_diff = y - dplyr::lag(y),
      x_diff = x - dplyr::lag(x)
      ) %>%
   ungroup(.)

data_trans

# A tibble: 6 x 8
  id    time      y     x y_demeaned x_demeaned y_diff x_diff
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1     1         1     2       -1          0       NA     NA
2 1     2         3     2        1          0        2      0
3 2     1         6     4        0.5       -1.5     NA     NA
4 2     2         5     7       -0.5        1.5     -1      3
5 3     1         9     6        0.5        0.5     NA     NA
6 3     2         8     5       -0.5       -0.5     -1     -1
```

Next, I will estimate FE and FD, separately. Take note of the `-1` *inside of* the specification. This removes the intercept.

```
### --- Estimation using the lm function on the 'transformed data'

lm_within <- lm(y_demeaned ~ x_demeaned - 1, data = data_trans)
lm_diff <- lm(y_diff ~ x_diff - 1, data = data_trans)

lm_within$coefficients[["x_demeaned"]]
[1] -0.2
lm_diff$coefficients[["x_diff"]]
[1] -0.2

### --- Estimation using the plm function

library(plm)

plm_within <- plm(y ~ x, data = data_trans, index = c("id", "time"), model = "within")
plm_diff <- plm(y ~ x - 1, data = data_trans, index = c("id", "time"), model = "fd")

summary(plm_within)[["coefficients"]]
  Estimate Std. Error    t-value  Pr(>|t|)
x     -0.2  0.5291503 -0.3779645 0.7418011
summary(plm_diff)[["coefficients"]]
  Estimate Std. Error    t-value  Pr(>|t|)
x     -0.2  0.5291503 -0.3779645 0.7418011
```

Note, the "within-estimator" in the `plm()` function omits the intercept for us. However, when we moved to the FD estimator, we needed to remove it *manually*. In fact, it is recommended to use -1 to remove the intercept term. To quote from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf) on page 86:

> For first–difference models, the intercept is maintained (which from a specification viewpoint amounts to allowing for a trend in the levels model). The user can exclude it from the estimated specification the usual way by adding "-1" to the model formula.

Interestingly, if you add *time* to your FE model, the coefficient on the time variable is equal to the intercept of the FD estimator. In sum, make sure you omit the intercept term if you want to demonstrate—explicitly—that the coefficients are similar.

Comment: Much better put!

Answer (score 1):

You can get them to match up by either

1. Dropping the intercept from the FD model.
2. Add a linear time trend to the FE model

The FD intercept corresponds to the linear time trend coefficient in levels, which you can see here:

$$y_{i,2}-y_{i,1}=\alpha_i-\alpha_i + \beta\cdot (x_{i,2}-x_{i,1})+\gamma \cdot (2-1)+\varepsilon_{i,2}-\varepsilon_{i,1}$$